# How to get the search list from pytube on python

Tags: python, pytube

```
from pytube import Search
s = Search('Dev')
print(s.results)
```

i was hoping how to get a list of items i can use rather than this
<pytube.**main**.YouTube object: videoId=g14RIIP8u8E>

i want get a list, add it to a dictionary and use it in the download function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.results` are already list, you just need to loop

```
from pytube import Search

s = Search('Learn Python')
for v in s.results:
  print(f"{v.title}\n{v.watch_url}\n")

# get object keys
keys = "\n".join([k for k in s.results[0].__dict__])
print(keys)
```

Comment: God bless you, do you mind i get it without list comprehension. Thanks a bunch

Comment: amin... for the `keys`? loop over `s.results[0].__dict__`