# How do I search for and download videos in pytube?

Tags: python, pytube

I want to create a song or video downloader in python with pytube. I have only seen that you can download videos if you have the link. I want to use the search feature in pytube and then download the first video that comes up. can you show me a snippet of how you can do this.

I have tried using the search in pytube but I do not know how to grab a link from a video or download it.

Comment: Have you read the documentation?  The `search` method returns to you a list of `YouTube` objects, just as if you had already fetched the link.  You just need to read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google is your friend.](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+get+urls+from+the+search+feature+of+pytube+python&rlz=1CAOEMI_enUS968US968&oq=how+to+get+urls+from+the+search+feature+of+pytube+python&aqs=chrome..69i57j33i160l4.11473j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&safe=active&ssui=on) Try searching for your answer online before posting a question here.

Regardless, this code should return a dictionary of results from your search [link](https://pytube.io/en/latest/user/search.html), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71894141/how-to-get-the-search-list-from-pytube-on-python)

```py
from pytube import Search

s = Search('Your search here')
searchResults = {}
for v in s.results:
  searchResults[v.title] = v.watch_url
```

To return a list of URLs:

```py
from pytube import Search

s = Search('Your search here')
searchResults = []
for v in s.results:
  searchResults.append(v.watch_url)
```

Comment: How would just grab the first link out of the list of links and save it to a variable

Comment: @GaboniBones searchResults[0] would be the index of the first link, so saving it to a variable: link = searchResults[0] would work.